# GA4 how to see Real Time Page Paths

Tags: google-analytics

I haven't used in Google Analytics in a long time.   I want to know in real time which URLs are being visited, but the closest widget I can find is "Page Title and Screen Name" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

But because very single page has the same Page Title (the developer made this site with Next.JS and never took the time to create a custom page title on each page), all views are lumped into the Page Title called "Home" (redacted in red).  Where in GA4 can I see in real time which urls are being visited?

---

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

The developer is using `import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'`.  SO he just puts `<GoogleTagManager gtmId="G-0000000"/>` on the `layout.txs` file.  He didn't do any other configuration

---

Also in the `Event count by Event Name`, if I click on `page_view`, all I see is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be a variable  that is passed by default called `page location`. This is the URL that a person was on.

---

1. In your screenshot, locate the `Event Count By Event Name`:

[image]

2. Click on `page_view` to see this:

[image]

3. Click on pagination at bottom right corner until you see this:

[image]

4. Click on `page_location` to see each url:

[image]

5. You can hover over each line to see full url, but for confidentiality reasons, I will not show a screenshot of this final step.

Comment: Thanks! Where in the GA4 web interface do I go to see data for `page location`?

Comment: If your looking at real time, you'll need to click down from the events card to the `page_view` event. From there, there should be a parameter of `page_location`. If you want non-realtime, you can go to explorer and add it as a dimension. I will say this though, with a JS app, if your property isn't setup to handle the routing fragments, the `page_location` parameter won't capture anything after the `#`. You have to manually push the full URL to that out of the box parameter.

Comment: I just clicked on the events card and `page_view` but it gives me variable names I don't recognize. I updated my question to show what I see after clicking `page_view`

Comment: Click the pagination arrow to see the last 4 variables that are being passed...

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just added screenshots to your answer to make it clear how to locate this data.